# Rules for LINQ to SQL across method boundaries

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

To keep my code cleaner I often try to break down parts of my data access code in LINQ to SQL into private sub-methods, just like with plain-old business logic code.  Let me give a very simplistic example:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetItemsFromRepository()
{
    var setA = from a in this.dataContext.TableA
               where /* criteria */
               select a.Prop;

    return DoSubquery(setA);
}

private IEnumerable<Item> DoSubQuery(IEnumerable<DateTimeOffset> set)
{
     return from item in set
            where /* criteria */
            select item;
}
```

I'm sure no one's imagination would be stretched by imagining more complex examples with deeper nesting or using results of sets to filter other queries.

My basic question is this:  I've seen some significant performance differences and even exceptions being thrown by just simply reorganizing LINQ to SQL code in private methods.  Can anyone explain the rules for these behaviors so that I can make informed decisions about how to write efficient, clean data access code?

Some questions I've had:

1) When does passage of System.Linq.Table instace to a method cause query execution?

2) When does using a System.Linq.Table in another query cause execution?

3) Are there limits to what types of operations (Take, First, Last, order by, etc.) can be applied to System.Linq.Table passed a parameters into a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the implicit cast:

```
public IQueryable<Item> GetItemsFromRepository()
{
    var setA = from a in this.dataContext.TableA
               where /* criteria */
               select a.Prop;

    return DoSubquery(setA);
}

private IQueryable<Item> DoSubQuery(IQueryable<DateTimeOffset> set)
{
     return from item in set
            where /* criteria */
            select item;
}
```

The implicit cast from `IQueryable<Item>` to `IEnumerable<Item>` is essentially the same as calling `AsEnumerable()` on your `IQueryable<Item>`. There are of course times when you want that, but you should leave things as `IQueryable` by default, so that the entire query can be performed on the database, rather than merely the `GetItemsFromRepository()` bit with the rest being done in memory.

The secondary questions:

> 1) When does passage of System.Linq.Table instace to a method cause query execution?

When something needs a final result, such as `Max()`, `ToList()`, etc. that is neither a queryable object, nor a loaded-as-it-goes enumerable.

Note though, that while `AsEnumerable()` does not cause query execution, it does mean that when execution does happen only that before the `AsEnumerable()` will be performed against the source datasource, this will then produce an on-demand in-memory datasource against which the rest will be performed.

> 2) When does using a System.Linq.Table in another query cause
>   execution?

The same as above. `Table<T>` implements `IQueryable<T>`. If you e.g. join two of them together, that won't yet cause anything to be executed.

> 3) Are there limits to what types of operations (Take,
>   First, Last, order by, etc.) can be applied to System.Linq.Table
>   passed a parameters into a method?

Those that are definted by `IQueryable<T>`.

Edit: Some clarification on the differences and similarities between `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable`.

Just about anything you can do on an `IQueryable` you can do on an `IEnumerable` and vice-versa, but how it's performed will be different.

Any given `IQueryable` implementation can be used in linq queries and will have all the linqy extension methods like `Take()`, `Select()`, `GroupBy` and so on.

Just how this is done, depends on the implementation. For example, `System.Linq.Data.Table` implements those methods by the query being turned into an SQL query, the results of which are turned into a objects on a as-loaded basis. So if `mySource` is a table then:

```
var filtered = from item in mySource
  where item.ID < 23
  select new{item.ID, item.Name};

foreach(var i in filtered)
  Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
```

Gets turned into SQL like:

```
select id, name from mySourceTable where id < 23
```

And then an enumerator is created from that such that on each call to `MoveNext()` another row is read from the results, and a new anonymous object created from it.

On the other hand, if `mySource` where a `List` or a `HashSet`, or anything else that implements `IEnumerable<T>` but doesn't have its own query engine, then the linq-to-objects code will turn it into something like:

```
foreach(var item in mySource)
  if(item.ID < 23)
    yield return new {item.ID, item.Name};
```

Which is about as efficiently as that code could be done in memory. The results will be the same, but the way to get them, would be different:

Now, since all `IQueryable<T>` can be converted into the equivalent `IEnumerable<T>` we could, if we wanted to, take the first `mySource` (where execution happens in a database) and do the following instead:

```
var filtered = from item in mySource.AsEnumerable()
  where item.ID < 23
  select new{item.ID, item.Name};
```

Here, while there is still nothing executed against the database until we iterate through the results or call something that examines all of those results, once we do so, it's as if we split the execution into two separate steps:

```
var asEnum = mySource.AsEnumerable();
var filtered = from item in asEnum
  where item.ID < 23
  select new{item.ID, item.Name};
```

The implemenatation of the first line would be to execute the SQL `SELECT * FROM mySourceTable`, and the execution of the rest would be like the linq-to-objects example above.

It's not hard to see how, if the database contained 10 items with an id < 23, and 50,000 items with an id higher, this is now much, much less performant.

As well as offering the explicity `AsEnumerable()` method, all `IQueryable<T>` can be implicitly cast to `IEnumerable<T>`. This lets us do `foreach` on them and use them with any other existing code that handles `IEnumerable<T>`, but if we accidentally do it at in inappropriate time, we can make queries much slower, and this is what was happening when your `DoSubQuery` was defined to take an `IEnumerable<DateTimeOffset>` and return an `IEnumerable<Item>`; it implicitly called `AsEnumerable()` on your `IQueryable<DateTimeOffset>` and your `IQueryable<Item>` and caused what could have been performed on the database to be performed in-memory.

For this reason, 99% of the time, we want to keep dealing in `IQueryable` until the very last moment.

As an example of the opposite though, just to point out that `AsEnumerable()` and the casts to `IEnumerable<T>` aren't there out of madness, we should consider two things. The first is that `IEnumerable<T>` lets us do things that can't be done otherwise, such as joining two completely different sources that don't know about each other (e.g. two different databases, a database and an XML file, etc.)

Another is that sometimes `IEnumerable<T>` is actually more efficient too. Consider:

```
IQueryable<IGrouping<string, int>> groupingQuery = from item in mySource select item.ID group by item.Name;
var list1 = groupingQuery.Select(grp => new {Name=grp.Key, Count=grp.Count()}).ToList();//fine
foreach(var grp in groupingQuery)//disaster!
  Console.WriteLine(grp.Count());
```

Here `groupingQuery` is set up as a queryable that does some grouping, but which hasn't been executed in anyway. When we create list1, then first we create a new `IQueryable` based on that, and the query engine does it's best to work out what the best SQL for it is, and comes up with something like:

```
select name, count(id) from mySourceTable group by name
```

Which is pretty efficiently performed. Then the rows are turned into objects, which are then put into a list.

On the other hand, with the second query, there isn't as natural a SQL conversion for a `group by` that doesn't perform aggregate methods on all of the non-grouped items, so the best the query engine can come up with is to first do:

```
select distinct name from mySourceTable,
```

And then for every name it receives, to do:

```
select id from mySourceTable where name = '{name found in last query goes here}'
```

And so on, should this mean 2 SQL queries, or 200,000.

In this case, we're much better working on `mySource.AsEnumerable()` because here it **is** more efficient to grab the whole table into memory first. (Even better still would be to work on `mySource.Select(item => new {item.ID, item.Name}).AsEnumerable()` because then we still only retrieve the columns we care about from the database, and switch to in-memory at that point).

The last bit is worth remembering because it breaks our rule that we should stay with `IQueryable<T>` as long as possible. It isn't something to worry about much, but it is worth keeping an eye on if you do grouping and find yourself with a very slow query.

Comment: Excellent response.  This is a good reference which I will certainly bookmark for later.

Answer (score 5):

The most important rule in terms of LINQ-to-SQL would be: don't return `IEnumerable<T>` unless you must - as the semantic is unclear. There are two schools of thought beyond that:

- if you return `IQueryable<T>`, it is *composable*, meaning the `where` from later queries is combined to make a single TSQL, but as a down-side, it is hard to fully test
- otherwise, return `List<T>` or similar, so it is clear that everything beyond that point is LINQ-to-Objects

Currently, you are doing something in the middle: collapsing it to LINQ-to-Objects (via `IEnumerable<T>`), but without it being obvious - and keeping the connection open in the middle (again, only a problem because it isn't obvious)

Comment: I can't agree with that. If you want to use Linq-to-objects, but don't need the extra functionality of a list, then it's a premature pessimisation.

Comment: @JonHanna besides, they can always use the first approach (`IQueryable<T>`) and just call `.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I get you now with that last comment. Yes, I'd favour `IEnumerable<T>` over `List<T>` in most - but not all - cases (and `IQueryable<T>` over it in most again), but I'd do the conversion through `AsEnumerable()` precisely to make the semantics clearer. Just casting to `IEnumerable<T>` leads to people having the questions the OP has, about why their code is suddenly slow.

Comment: Indeed, I think confusion on the distinctions we're talking about may be what's led to OP into error. Think I'll add a bit to my answer, so...